How to theoretically calculate (or at least know ordering) of on-site energy of orbitals using tight binding (TB) method?
I am using TB method to calculate eigenvalues and band diagrams for systems of Ag001 and Sn001 considering only s and px orbitals. Though both matrices will look same but on site energy for s and p orbitals of Ag and Sn will be different. I want to know if there is a way to know whose on site energy will be greater?
